# How and where can I create a getUserById function?

Tags: authentication, strapi

I'm trying to find a way to get users in strapi by ID. But I don't have access to the User identity in the controller.

I have tried go write a function in the controller and service both diedn't work cause I cant access the find or findOne method

```
getById: async(ctx) => {
    console.log('from user controller', ctx);
    return User.find({ _id: ctx.request.body.id })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you are using typeorm? and User is your User repository?

So in that case a small change should do

```
getById: async(ctx) => {
    console.log('from user controller', ctx);
    return User.find({ where: {_id: ctx.request.body.id} })
}
```

(Also make sure you have sanitized your input somewhere)

Comment: Yes user is my repo. The problem, is that User is always undefined

Comment: @Justin could you add a bit more code. Are you using classes? or objects? I need a bit more context to help you further.